# TX20E PCI WiFi adapter breaks Linux shutdown/suspend - it boots up after shutdown/suspend

Tags: linux, wifi, drivers, shutdown, pci

Have dual boot:

- Fedora Linux 39
- Windows 10

Can successfully shutdown/sleep in windows, but attempt to shutdown/suspend in Linux causes PC to turn on.

Kernel: 6.6.14-200.fc39.x86_64

```bash
> $ inxi -Fxzd
System:
  Kernel: 6.6.14-200.fc39.x86_64 arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc
    v: 2.40-13.fc39 Desktop: GNOME v: 45.3 Distro: Fedora release 39 (Thirty
    Nine)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Gigabyte product: B450 AORUS PRO v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Gigabyte model: B450 AORUS PRO-CF serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: F64h date: 12/25/2023
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 7 2700 bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen+ rev: 2
    cache: L1: 768 KiB L2: 4 MiB L3: 16 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1677 high: 2477 min/max: 1550/3200 boost: enabled cores:
    1: 1329 2: 2353 3: 1550 4: 1331 5: 2477 6: 1550 7: 1550 8: 1550 9: 1550
    10: 1550 11: 1550 12: 1550 13: 2300 14: 1550 15: 1550 16: 1550
    bogomips: 102207
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
...
Network:
  Device-1: Intel I211 Gigabit Network vendor: Gigabyte driver: igb v: kernel
    port: e000 bus-ID: 04:00.0
  IF: eno1 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8852BE PCIe 802.11ax Wireless Network
    vendor: AzureWave driver: rtw89_8852be v: kernel port: d000 bus-ID: 08:00.0
  IF: wlp8s0 state: up mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: docker0 state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: IMC Networks Bluetooth Radio driver: btusb v: 0.8 type: USB
    bus-ID: 1-7:2
  Report: btmgmt ID: hci0 rfk-id: 4 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 5.3
    lmp-v: 12
....
```

I have TX20E PCI-E WiFi Adapter. Sometimes rfkill of radio devices helped me:

```bash
$ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 1 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
 4 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
$ rfkill block 1
$ rfkill block 4
```

And after it PC might successfully shutdown/sleep, but it's not stable solution

```bash
$ sudo dmidecode | grep Wake-up
    Wake-up Type: PCI PME#
```

I'm sure the reason is WiFi PCIE TX20E adapter (`rtw89_8852be` driver), coz I've just ejected it and tried to susped/shutdown - success.

Any idea how to fix it and make it possible to shutdown/sleep with WiFi card?

Comment: 1. Tried adding from 70-rtw89.conf to /etc/modprobe.d/ | /usr/lib/modprobe.d/ using [this guide](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89/tree/main#:~:text=Their%20BIOS%20does%20not%20handle%20the%20PCIe%20interface%20correctly) - still fail. Driver that i'm using shipped with Fedora image, not installed from repo

Comment: Please run `sudo ethtool wlp8s0` and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by clearing directory
`/lib/modules/6.6.14-200.fc39.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw89/`

Then install [8852be](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw8852be) driver and all works fine.

```bash
e@fedora:~$ sudo !!
sudo lsmod | grep 8852
8852be               5193728  0
```